# How To concatenate Two Json object in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web, asp.net-web-api

[image: This one is of other][image: This one is the output][image: This is what i am getting in lstrng][image: This is what i am getting in a]How to concatenate the result `Json(new{lstrng,a}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. I want to see result of lstrng and a collectively. My code is

```
var a = this.abc();  
JsonResult json =Json(new{lstrng,a}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;  
return json;
```

here abc is an other method and lstrng is the result of current method

```
public JsonResult gFbrRecord()
    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.gfbrdata();
        //this is for getordert tart
        List<fbrData> lstrng = new List<fbrData>(10000);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            lstrng.Add(new fbrData
            {  
               FBRInvoiceNumber = dr["FBR_NUM"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["FBR_NUM"]) : Convert.ToString(""),
                POSID = dr["REG_NUM"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["REG_NUM"]) : Convert.ToInt32(0),
               });               

        }

        var a = this.abc();                 
        JsonResult json =Json(new{lstrng,a}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return json;
    }
     public JsonResult abc() {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.gfbrdata();
        List<fbr1> lstrng = new List<fbr1>(10000);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            lstrng.Add(new fbr1
            {  
                DetailSerialNo = dr["SRL_NUM"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["SRL_NUM"]) : Convert.ToInt32(0),                   
                ItemCode = dr["ITM_COD"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToString(dr["ITM_COD"]) : Convert.ToString(""),
              });

        }

        JsonResult json = Json(lstrng, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        json.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return json;
    }
}
```

[image: This one is the output i am getting not]

Comment: what you mean by concatenate?

Comment: what the content inside `lstrng` & `a`?

Comment: Concatenate means that i want to get the result in one object return just one object

Comment: lstrng is a resultof one method and a is the reslut of other method

Comment: lstrng contain list of data and a contain json result

Comment: @MalikRizwan, could you please give an example and expected output so it will be easy to provide you an answer

Comment: Paste code not images

Comment: your `lstrng` and `a` both an array and you want to concatenate item from both array on same indices. means `lstrng[0]` concat with `a[0]` and `lstrng[1]`  concat with `a[1]` and so on... right?

Comment: @er-shoaib sure why not i mention two screenshoot above i want to show all the result in one array.If i have multiple records with same FBRInvoiceNumber i want to show it in one array instead of repeating my method for every call

Comment: true you are right

Comment: @MalikRizwan,let me clear,  you want to concat item form both array by indices or by FBRInvoiceNumber?

Comment: i want it by indices

Comment: @MalikRizwan, ok got it, could you please provide sample data from both of array to prepare answer for you.

Comment: @er-shoaib i mention the code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184749/discussion-between-malik-rizwan-and-er-shoaib).

Comment: @BWA please check the code

Comment: @MalikRizwan, I added my answer below, just you need to adjust my solution to your code.

Comment: @er-shoaib you can check screenshoot from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query your both list and select mutiple items form second list that
have same id with single item in first list

```
public JsonResult gFbrRecord()
    {
        DataSet ds1 = dblayer.gfbrdata();
        List<fbrData> lstrng1 = new List<fbrData>(10000);

        //Your other stuff here

        DataSet ds2 = dblayer.gfbrdata();
        List<fbr1> lstrng2 = new List<fbr1>(10000);

        //Your other stuff here

        var result = (from item1 in lstrng1
                      select new
                      {
                          FBRInvoiceNumber = item1.FBRInvoiceNumber,
                          POSID = item1.POSID,
                          SRL_NUM = item1.SRL_NUM,
                          Data = (from item2 in lstrng2
                                  where item2.SRL_NUM == item1.SRL_NUM
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      DetailSerialNo = item2.DetailSerialNo,
                                      ItemCode = item2.ItemCode
                                  }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

---

**Alternative**

Basically I provide you an example code that should work for concatenation of two json objects

1) This method fetch record from database and populate list and then `JToken` will be created from this list

```
public static JToken Method1()
{
    DataSet ds = dblayer.gfbrdata();
    List<fbrData> lstrng = new List<fbrData>(10000);

    //Your other stuff here

    JToken jToken = JToken.FromObject(lstrng);
    return jToken;
}
```

`JToken` return by above method is look like

```
[
  {
    "FBRInvoiceNumber": "ABC",
    "POSID": 110034,
    "SRL_NUM": 123
  },
  {
    "FBRInvoiceNumber": "PQR",
    "POSID": 210035,
    "SRL_NUM": 456
  }
]
```

2) This method is also same like above method but only difference is that this method fetches record from database other than above method.

```
public static JToken Method2()
{
    DataSet ds = dblayer.gfbrdata();
    List<fbr1> lstrng = new List<fbr1>(10000);

    //Your other stuff here

    JToken jToken = JToken.FromObject(lstrng);
    return jToken;
}
```

`JToken` return by above method is look like

```
[
  {
    "DetailSerialNo": 8,
    "ItemCode": "700275",
    "SRL_NUM": 123
  },
  {
    "DetailSerialNo": 9,
    "ItemCode": "800279",
    "SRL_NUM": 456
  }
]
```

3) Now the below function can concatenate each of object in both of array on same index.

Since you mentioned in above comment that

> you want to concatenate each of your object in both array by same property key `SRL_NUM` value.

```
public static JToken Concat(JToken jToken1, JToken jToken2)
{
    JArray jArray = new JArray();

    foreach (JObject jObject1 in jToken1.ToObject<JArray>())
    {
        var value1 = jObject1.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "SRL_NUM").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        foreach (JObject jObject2 in jToken2.ToObject<JArray>())
        {
            var value2 = jObject2.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "SRL_NUM").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(value1) == Convert.ToInt32(value2))
            {
                jObject1.Merge(jObject2, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat });
                jArray.Add(jObject1);
            }
        }
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

4) Then you can use above method to your action method

```
public ContentResult gFbrRecord()
{
    JToken jToken1 = Method1();
    JToken jToken2 = Method2();

    var result = Concat(jToken1, jToken2);

    return Content(result.ToString(), "application/json");
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit1:**

If you array contains more than one `SRL_NUM` in second array then the below method can concatenate all items with same `SRL_NUM` with first array item with same `SRL_NUM`.

```
public static JToken Concat(JToken jToken1, JToken jToken2)
{
    JArray jArray = new JArray();

    foreach (JObject jObject1 in jToken1.ToObject<JArray>())
    {
        var value = jObject1.Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "SRL_NUM").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        var result = jToken2.ToObject<JArray>().ToObject<JObject[]>().Properties().Where(x => x.Name == "SRL_NUM" && Convert.ToInt32(x.Value) == Convert.ToInt32(value)).Select(x => x.Parent);

        JArray jAr = new JArray();

        foreach (JObject obj in result)
        {
            jAr.Add(obj);
        }

        JObject jObject = new JObject();

        jObject.Merge(jObject1, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat });
        jObject.Add("Data", jAr);

        jArray.Add(jObject);
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks brother for superb effort i am geting everything ok  till at the jason return but when i show result on postman is not showing anything just empty arrays are showing but in API its showing values

Comment: this is the HTTPGET api right? then try it with browser. if it shows you result then API works fine. then try it with postman and manage some setting like select JSON option from drop down.

Comment: Love you brother Thanks alot for your concern and tremendous effort and help.Its make my day

Comment: I want same output which you mentioned above but here i am getting empty array

Comment: sir my record are just repeating except this everything ok

Comment: Thanks alot got the desired output bunddle of thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want a result of  list  just merge a and lstrng??
 `a.Data.AddRang(lstrng.Data)`
This Code will merge the two of arr  and you need define a List of a.Data in your lstrng model.